# In awk, how do I prepend a string to a pattern search print

Tags: linux, awk

Sorry for the easy question, I can't seem to find the answer. We have a file that contains a lot of emails.

```
<To: someemail@email.com>
<Cc: Otheremail@email.com>
<From: othermail@mail.com>

hello person here is random text
```

etc., repeat with 20+ emails

The teacher wants, in awk, the students to print the lines containing emails, while prepending "email =" to the beginning. his hint was to use To: From: and Cc: as pattern searches. His ideal output would be

```
email = someemail@email.com
email = Otheremail@email.com
email = othermail@mail.com
```

but he will also take

```
email = <To: someemail@email.com>
email = <Cc: Otheremail@email.com>
email = <From: othermail@mail.com>
```

I can get it to print the latter example (I'm clueless how to remove the garbage characters from each example, they are not consistent from one email to another) but how do I prepend `email =` ?

so far I have

```
awk '/To:|From:|Cc:/ {print}' file
```

I've also tried a bunch of other weird things that have only given syntax errors

Thank you!

Comment: You are very close.  All you have to do is remember that `print` can take parameters, string literals or special variables that correspond to the whole string or parts of it. You already know what string literal to add (that's `email=`).  Now, all you gotta do, is read the `awk` manual to figure out what those parameters are. Another thing: if the input data always has same number of the email lines ( the to, from, cc lines) you don't even need a pattern, just match the line number. Good luck and keep going - you're almost there !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following would do what you need:

```
awk '/To:|From:|Cc:/ {$2=substr($2,1,length($2)-1); print "email = ", $2 }' file
```

This bit:

```
{$2=substr($2,1,length($2)-1)
```

Takes the second element in the string, which is something like `someemail@email.com>`, and removes the last character, `>`.

Then you just print the string you want `"email = "`, along with the edited second element, `$2`:

```
print "email = ", $2
```

The result looks like this:

```
email =  someemail@email.com
email =  Otheremail@email.com
email =  othermail@mail.com
```

It's worth familiarizing yourself with how print works: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print-Examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Command

`awk -F ":" '/To|Cc|From/{gsub(">","",$2);print "email ="$2}'`  filename

output

```
email = someemail@email.com
email = Otheremail@email.com
email = othermail@mail.com
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'To|Cc|From')
q=open('filename','r')
for i in q:
    if re.search(k,i):
        w=i.split(":")[1].replace(">","")
        print "email = {0}".format(w).strip()
```

output

```
email =  someemail@email.com
email =  Otheremail@email.com
email =  othermail@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object is to learn `awk` then you could try out some of the other functionality. This relies a bit on the formatting of your file but then, so do the other answers, so

```
awk -F'>|<| ' -v OFS=" = " '/To:|From:|Cc:/{print "E-mail", $(NF-1)}' file

E-mail = someemail@email.com
E-mail = Otheremail@email.com
E-mail = othermail@mail.com
```

First you can set up your input field separator `-F` as an extended regular expression, an ERE, so that it breaks your input line `$0` on `<` or `>` or

```
-F'>|<| '
```

Doing this cleans the extra character from the end of the email address but leaves `$1` empty (because of the leading `<`), `$2` contains your filtering field, `$3` the email address and there is an empty `$4` at the end (because of the trailing `>`)

Then being lazy you can set the output field separator to `=` so whenever you print a series of fields the default behaviour is to insert `=` and not just   between the fields

```
-v OFS=" = "
```

Your filtering is the same on `$0` but when you print, because you split the input string `$0` into 4 (and the number of fields, the special `awk` variable, `NF`=4) you want to print `$3`, which is also `$(NF-1)` in this case

```
'/To:|From:|Cc:/{print "E-mail", $(NF-1)}' file
```

And because you have pulled your filter field out expressly then you can guard against an accidental match elsewhere in `$0` by looking for an explicit match in `$2` if you want.

```
'$2=="To:"||$2=="From:"||$2=="Cc:"{......
```